# layout does not move up even after adjustPan,adjustResize

Tags: android, android-layout

My code is as shown below:

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<activity
        android:name=".activity.LogInActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

activity_login.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/ic_dashback"
   >


    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/card_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="235dp"
            android:layout_height="264dp"
            android:background="@color/colorMobster7B"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingLeft="20dp"
            android:paddingRight="20dp">


            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/userName"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
                android:background="@drawable/background_edittext_login"
                android:hint="Email"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:minLines="1"
                android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:textColor="@color/colorBlackCurrent"
                android:textColorHint="@color/colorBlackCurrent"
                android:textSize="13sp" />


            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/password"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/userName"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:background="@drawable/background_edittext_login"
                android:hint="Password"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:minLines="1"
                android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:textColor="@color/colorBlackCurrent"
                android:textColorHint="@color/colorBlackCurrent"
                android:textSize="13sp" />


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/forgotPassword"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/password"
                android:layout_marginTop="13dp"
                android:text="Forgot Password"
                android:textSize="13sp" />


            <Button
                android:id="@+id/loginButton"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/forgotPassword"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="27dp"
                android:background="@color/colorBlackCurrent"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|center"
                android:text="LOGIN"
                android:textAllCaps="true"
                android:textColor="@color/colorMobster7B"
                android:textSize="17sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/createAccount"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/loginButton"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:text="Create account"
                android:textAllCaps="true"
                android:textSize="17sp" />
        </RelativeLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/card_view"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/bottomText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Powered by"
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            android:textColor="@color/colorMobster7B"
            android:textSize="12sp" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="55dp"
            android:layout_height="19dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/bottomText"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_quflip" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="105dp"
        android:visibility="invisible" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

LoginActivity.java

```
public class LogInActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
.....
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
        this.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE);
.....
}
}
```

Now, here my layout is for tablet. What I want is , as soon as keyboard open up, the whole layout should move upward, rather than area of particular edittexts.
I have already tried "adjustPan","adjustResize", "adjustPan|adjustResize" and I have already defined each layout as relativelayout. But nothing works , so what should I do to make it work?

Comment: try to add fitsystemWindow=true in relativelayout

Comment: In which relative layout should I put fitsystemWindow=true ? and what windowsSoftInputMode flag should I use?

Comment: stateHidden|adjustResize and top most parent relative

Comment: No,it is not giving the  effect to push the whole layout up. For that I have updated my code in the post above. and let me know if I have not done exactly as you suggested.

Comment: try one thing. put your second REelative layout inside Scrollview.

Comment: Is your activity fullscreen?

Comment: @R.R.M yes, activity is full screen

Comment: @DivyeshPatel if i put scrollview then relative layout does not remain in center

Comment: for that add fillViewport=true in Scrollview

Comment: @DivyeshPatel your solution worked

Answer (score 0):

Inside `Manifest` define `android:windowSoftInputMode` as below.

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize"
```

An also inside `Activity` `programmatically` do this.

```
this.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE);
```

**EDIT**

Also add this inside `Manifest` and try.

```
android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
```

I have tested output using your `layout`.

Below is tablet output.

[image]

Comment: I have done exactly the way you have shown, but it is not working for me

Comment: @MrugeshThaker Check and try edited one. Try your luck. It's all working for me as you can see.

Comment: I have updated my code in the post,can you tell me that my and your code is same. Plus I have put screenorientation=landscape

Comment: @MrugeshThaker Code is same.

Comment: but it is not giving the same effect in my device